# Filter with a sub level query EF linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this data from DB

```
  "objeto": {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Selección",
    "status": false,
    "VisitasVariableTipo": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "idVariableTipo": 1,
        "VariablesTipo": {
          "id": 1,
          "titulo": "Fecha de Visita Selección",
          "Variables": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "respuesta": "01/07/2021",
              "RespuestasVariables": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "idRespuestaTipoFirma": 1,
                  "idVariable": 1,
                  "RespuestasVariablesDetalle": [
                    {
                      "id": 1,
                      "idRespuestaVariable": 1,
                      "idNotaClinica": 8,
                      "etiqueta": null,
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": 1002,
                  "idRespuestaTipoFirma": 1002,
                  "idVariable": 1,
                  "RespuestasVariablesDetalle": [
                    {
                      "id": 1002,
                      "idRespuestaVariable": 1002,
                      "idNotaClinica": 5,
                      "etiqueta": null,
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "Variables": [],
              "CatalogoDatosTipo": {
                "id": 0,
                "tipo": null,
                "CatalogoDatos": null
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And I want to use linq to filter the that and filter by RespuestasVariablesDetalle.idNotaClinica, for example

```
var visita = db.NotasClinicas
                    .Where(nc => nc.Visitas.Visitas_Variable_Tipo
                    .Any(vvt => vvt.Variables_Tipo.Variables
                    .Any( v => v.Respuestas_Variables
                    .Any(rr =>  rr.RespuestasVariablesDetalle.idNotaClinica == 5  ) ) ) ).First().Visitas;
```

I don't know what method should I use to make this work, I want to get the next results

```
  "objeto": {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Selección",
    "status": false,
    "VisitasVariableTipo": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "idVariableTipo": 1,
        "VariablesTipo": {
          "id": 1,
          "titulo": "Fecha de Visita Selección",
          "Variables": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "respuesta": "01/07/2021",
              "RespuestasVariables": [
                {
                  "id": 1002,
                  "idRespuestaTipoFirma": 1002,
                  "idVariable": 1,
                  "RespuestasVariablesDetalle": [
                    {
                      "id": 1002,
                      "idRespuestaVariable": 1002,
                      "idNotaClinica": 5,
                      "etiqueta": null,
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "Variables": [],
              "CatalogoDatosTipo": {
                "id": 0,
                "tipo": null,
                "CatalogoDatos": null
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I don't know if there is a method that I can use, or should I filter the data after getting the result, but I don't want because I believe  may be a slower query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

    foreach (var tipo in jsonDeserialized.objeto.VisitasVariableTipo)
    {
        foreach (var variab in tipo.VariablesTipo.Variables)
        {
variab.RespuestasVariables.RemoveAll(i=> i.RespuestasVariablesDetalle.Any(a=> a.idNotaClinica !=5));
        }
    }

    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDeserialized);
```

Output

```
{
  "objeto": {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Selección",
    "status": false,
    "VisitasVariableTipo": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "idVariableTipo": 1,
        "VariablesTipo": {
          "id": 1,
          "titulo": "Fecha de Visita Selección",
          "Variables": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "respuesta": "01/07/2021",
              "RespuestasVariables": [
                {
                  "id": 1002,
                  "idRespuestaTipoFirma": 1002,
                  "idVariable": 1,
                  "RespuestasVariablesDetalle": [
                    {
                      "id": 1002,
                      "idRespuestaVariable": 1002,
                      "idNotaClinica": 5,
                      "etiqueta": null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "Variables": [],
              "CatalogoDatosTipo": {
                "id": 0,
                "tipo": null,
                "CatalogoDatos": null
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public Objeto objeto { get; set; }
}

public class RespuestasVariablesDetalle
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idRespuestaVariable { get; set; }
    public int idNotaClinica { get; set; }
    public string etiqueta { get; set; }
}

public class RespuestasVariable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idRespuestaTipoFirma { get; set; }
    public int idVariable { get; set; }
    public List<RespuestasVariablesDetalle> RespuestasVariablesDetalle { get; set; }
}

public class CatalogoDatosTipo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public object tipo { get; set; }
    public object CatalogoDatos { get; set; }
}

public class Variable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string respuesta { get; set; }
    public List<RespuestasVariable> RespuestasVariables { get; set; }
    public List<object> Variables { get; set; }
    public CatalogoDatosTipo CatalogoDatosTipo { get; set; }

    internal void SelectMany(Func<object, object> p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class VariablesTipo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public List<Variable> Variables { get; set; }
}

public class VisitasVariableTipo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idVariableTipo { get; set; }
    public VariablesTipo VariablesTipo { get; set; }
}

public class Objeto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public List<VisitasVariableTipo> VisitasVariableTipo { get; set; }
}
```